# Copy the files inside the folders of S3 bucket source and destination

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

This piece of code copies all the folders and files within the source bucket to the destination bucket. There are no errors resulting from this code.

However, under the source_bucket I have a folder and I want to copy only the files from that folder to the destination bucket and its specific folder, this code copies all the files/folders from the source bucket to the destination bucket. I don't have enough examples in the internet to fulfill this requirement.

```
import boto3
from sagemaker import get_execution_role

role = get_execution_role()
print(role)

sts_client = boto3.client('sts')

assumed_role_object=sts_client.assume_role(
    RoleArn=role,
    RoleSessionName="AssumeRoleSession1"
)

print(assumed_role_object)

# From the response that contains the assumed role, get the temporary 
# credentials that can be used to make subsequent API calls
credentials=assumed_role_object['Credentials']

# Use the temporary credentials that AssumeRole returns to make a 
# connection to Amazon S3  
s3_resource=boto3.resource(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'],
)

src_bucket = "source_bucket"
dest_bucket = "destination_bucket"

# Iterate All Objects in Your S3 Bucket Over the for Loop
for file in s3_resource.Bucket(src_bucket).objects.all():

    #Create a Soucre Dictionary That Specifies Bucket Name and Key Name of the Object to Be Copied
    copy_source = {
    'Bucket': src_bucket,
    'Key': file.key
    }
    
    print("Copy source", copy_source)

    s3_resource.meta.client.copy(copy_source, dest_bucket, file.key)
```

Comment: You forgot to explain what's wrong with the your code. Any errors?

Comment: @Marcin, I dont get any errors from this code however I dont know how to copy the files from a folder in source bucket to the destination bucket/folder. This code copies all the files/folders from the source and paste it to the destination bucket.

Comment: You can [filter](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/bucket/objects.html#filter) objects on a given prefix.

Comment: Which part are you stuck on? Is it knowing what objects are in a 'folder', or knowing how to copy objects to a specific folder in a destination bucket?

Comment: @jarmod, It worked perfectly fine with the filter from the src_bucket, how to choose the destination folder from the destination bucket

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, filter option using Prefix worked for source bucket to pick the folder. How about choosing the destination folder from the destination bucket.

Comment: There is no destination folder in the APIs. Each object simply has a key. So, for each object, pre-calculate the key that you want the destination object to have. If you're copying from `dogs/snoopy.png` to `dogs/snoopy.png` then just use the source object key., If copying from `dogs/snoopy.png` to `archive/dogs/snoopy.png` then just use the source object key but add a prefix e.g. `f"archive/{file.key}"` etc.

Answer (score 1):

The `Key` is the 'filename' of an object.

The Key **includes the full path** of the object.

For example, an object with a Key of `invoices/january.txt` will *appear* to be in a folder called `invoices`. However, the folder does not actually exist. Amazon S3 does not use folders. Instead, the part of the Key before the final slash is called a **Prefix**.

If you wanted to copy the `invoices/january.txt` object to a folder called `monthly`, then you would specify a destination key of `monthly/january.txt`. This becomes the Key of the new object. When viewing the object in the Amazon S3 management console, the object would appear to be called `january.txt` and would appear to be in a folder called `monthly`, but that it just how the console is displaying it.

Therefore, when copying an object, ensure that the Key is set to the full path of the object, including the part you would normally associated with a filename:

```py
source_key = 'invoices/january.txt'
destination_key = 'monthly/january.txt'

copy_source = {
    'Bucket': source_bucket,
    'Key': source_key
}
    
s3_resource.meta.client.copy(copy_source, destination_bucket, destination_key)
```

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein for your reply. In my scenario, I have 10 files inside the folder of the source bucket whilst I want to copy all those 10 files to destination (bucket/folder). Specifying key will limit me to mention only a single file to copy. Kindly let me know how I can copy multiple files from a S3 bucket/folder to  destination S3 bucket/folder

Comment: The Amazon S3 'copy' command will only copy one object per call. Therefore, you will need to loop through your list of objects and copy each object separately.